# Specialize template class depending on trait

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I am attempting to figure out how to special a template class based upon the result of a template.  For example, suppose I have the following basic template class:

```
enum class BasicType
{
    UNKNOWN,
    PRIMITIVE,
    OBJECT
};

template <typename T>
struct traits
{
    static constexpr BasicType type = BasicType::UNKNOWN;
};
```

I want to be able to create a specialization of traits, for example, for any types where std::is_integral_v is true.  And then another specialization where another traits is true.

I tried something like this

```
template <typename T>
struct traits<std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, T>>
{
    static constexpr BasicType type = BasicType::PRIMITIVE;
};
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close, but the problem with using enable_if like this is that it prevents type deduction. Basically, the compiler is unable to ever match your template specialization. What you can do, though, is to move the enable_if part to a second template parameter next to your `T` so it can be deduced:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct traits
{
    static constexpr BasicType type = BasicType::UNKNOWN;
};

template <typename T>
struct traits<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
{
    static constexpr BasicType type = BasicType::PRIMITIVE;
};
```

This works because `T` is no longer hidden behind another template. The compiler is still unable to deduce `T` from `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>`, but because you also specified `T` direclty here: `struct traits<T, ...>`, the compiler can deduce `T` this way, which is enough to match your specialization.

[example](https://godbolt.org/z/M84Yx66aj)